# Not sure why divs won't fade in?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically I'm trying to get these div's to fade in but they won't! I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but what i'm trying to do is gain the skills to make animations similar to this website: http://theme-fusion.com/avada/ When you scroll down elements just appear.I think it looks amazing! 
If anyone knows a site that teaches this or a video it would be much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>    
<body>
<style type="text/css">
#container
{
    height:2000px;    
}    
#container DIV
{ 
    margin:50px; 
    padding:50px; 
    background-color:lightgreen; 
}    
.hideme
{
    opacity:0;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {        
    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){        
        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){                
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();                
            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){                    
                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);                        
            }                
        });         
    });        
});
</script>
<div id="container">        
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>
    <div class="hideme">Fade In</div>        
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/ak9Hb/7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is jquery loading properly?  I had to add "https:" to get it to load on my side:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Your code worked fine once jquery loaded.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Not sure why I had to add https: because I copied it from the google libary. 
By any chance would you know... Is this what websites do when they fade in elements on scroll?

Comment: I don't know what other websites do to fade in on scroll but your code works.  The answer below suggests using fadeIn().  fadeIn is an option if you want to set your divs to display:none.  Your approach keeps them in the flow and simply removes the opacity.  Both ways would work.

Comment: Thanks... Could you maybe do a jsFiddle demo of the fadein option? If you have time would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like "Just Code" already made jsFiddle demo using FadeIn above: http://jsfiddle.net/ak9Hb/7/

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use fadeIn() instead of changing opacity?

If you dont want to use fadeIn(), give the element some transition.

```
div {
// your style
-webkit-transition: all .5s;
-moz-transition: all .5s;
transition: all .5s;
}
```

Then, use the .css() function on it in your JS

```
$(element).css('opacity',1);
```

Also, instead of `#container DIV` use `#container div` (lowercase), just in case.

**edit:**
If you want to use fadeIn(), first, give the element an inline style `display: none;` and then call `$(element).fadeIn('slow/fast/miliseconds')`
This works much better actually.

Comment: Thanks for contributing... Explained well and both are good options :)